# QueryPath outerHTML (jQuery for php)

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

I am using

gravitypdf/querypath (from composer)

I am trying to achieve this function from jQuery/JS in PHP QueryPath:

```
jQuery("html")[0].outerHTML;
```

I have tried the following:

```
echo (string) qp($html, $filter)->parents(":root"); // can't convert document to string

echo qp($html, $filter)->parents(":root")->html(); // returns inner HTML instead of outer HTML
```

edit, also tried:

```
echo qp($html, $filter)->parents(":root")->prop('outerHTML'); // prop doesn't exist

echo qp($html, $filter)->parents(":root")->outerHTML; // always returns empty string

// XMLSerializer JS object doesn't exist in PHP...
```

The issue is that the outerHTML property doesn't exist in queryPath...

please help me solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this function in a unit test document:

```
echo $doc->parents(":root")->get(0)->ownerDocument->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('html').prop('outerHTML')
```

or

```
$(document).outerHTML
```

or

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)
```

Comment: None of these worked :(